# iterate array of arrays in mustache

Tags: php, arrays, mustache

I am new to Mustache, please bear with me :)

I have array like this:

```
array(1) (
    "school" => array(2) (
        0 => array(12) (
            "school_code" => string(4) "Organics"
            "school_name" => string(27) "Biology"
            "school_city" => string(4) "Bremmen"
            "classes" => array(1) (
                0 => array(14) (
                    "location" => string(4) "south1"
                    "startdate" => string(10) "2013-11-11"
                    "enddate" => string(10) "2013-12-05"
                )
            )
        )
        1 => array(12) (
            "school_code" => string(4) "Anorganics"
            "school_name" => string(27) "Biology"
            "school_city" => string(4) "Augsburg"
            "classes" => array(3) (
                1 => array(14) (
                    "location" => string(4) "south2"
                    "startdate" => string(10) "2013-11-11"
                    "enddate" => string(10) "2013-12-05"
                )
                2 => array(14) (                    
            "location" => string(4) "south3"
                    "startdate" => string(10) "2013-08-22"
                    "enddate" => string(10) "2014-01-05"
                )
                3 => array(14) (
                    "location" => string(4) "south4"
                    "startdate" => string(10) "2013-11-11"
                    "enddate" => string(10) "2013-12-05"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

How i can iterate this in mustache.

i wanna show classes by school.

Thanks in advance.

My template is:

```
{{#school}}     
                    {{#has_missing_classes}}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="location faded">Unavailable</td>
                        <td class="address">Unavailable</td>
                        <td class="address">Unavailable</td>
                        <td class="actions">
                            <a></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="separator">
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/has_missing_classes}}


                    {{#classes}}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Location"><a href="{{dashboard_uri}}/classes/edit/{{Location}}">{{Location}}</a></td>
                        <td {{^StartDate}}class="faded"{{/StartDate}}>
                            {{StartDate}}
                            {{^StartDate}}Unavailable{{/StartDate}}
                        </td>
                        <td class="actions">
                            <a href="{{dashboard_uri}}/classes/edit/{{Id}}" class="edit" data-tooltip>Update Information</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/classes}}
                    {{^classes}}
                     <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" class="empty">
                            <p>
                                No records found.<br />
                            </p>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                    {{/classes}}
        {{/school}}
```

In this moment i can show all schools, but just first have classes attached.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In best case, i can show all schools, but is shown classes just to first school. if i put filter just on one record from school, is show correct with all classes.Just one by one school, never all school with their classes.

Comment: Please show your template and code for rendering, in addition to the data. There's not much we can do without all three :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($myArray[0]['school'] as $item){
    if($item['school_name'] == "Biology"){ //Biology for example
     // some code 
    }
```